# Linux C/C++ Application Deployment

Tags: c, linux, installation, dependencies

I've developed a project in C/C++ for Linux environment and it works great on my machine. I decided to move this application to another machine (VPS). After first run I realized that the new machine doesn't have some dependencies of this application. Some might suggest linking your application statically but this doesn't work for me because of some technical problems I have. So my question is how can I move my application with all dependencies preferably packed like a setup program in Windows and install it on the new machine?

This is my program's dependency list :

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdcf123000)
    libmicrohttpd.so.12 => /usr/local/lib/libmicrohttpd.so.12 (0x00007f653074a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6530359000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f653013a000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007f652fdd4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6530b71000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f652fbb7000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007f652f888000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f652f66b000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f652f2ed000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007f652f0da000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f652eea4000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007f652ec70000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f652e9ef000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f652e7e7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f652e5e3000)
```

Comment: Building a deb or rpm allows you to list dependencies.

Comment: It is normal for Linux development to have a build farm that builds packages for all targeted distributions. Installing a package should also install the dependencies if done right. And to provide a source code package for unsupported platforms so they can build it themselves.